# Sharepoint. ID Column exists in list, and all items view but not in list settings

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, list-view, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

How do I find my ID column? It exists in my List and in my all items view but not in list settings.

I am trying to do a second field where I concat the ID to a string.

Where is it? how come I cant reference it in my formula?

Comment: Go to list settings > click on any column name to open column settings >  from URL, replace the column name at The ends Of the URL  with ID to open column Settings For ID column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, Microsoft does not support using ID column in the SharePoint calculated column formulas.

> You cannot reference the ID of a row for a newly inserted row. The ID does not yet exist when the calculation is performed.

**Reference**

[Introduction to SharePoint formulas and functions](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/introduction-to-sharepoint-formulas-and-functions-94e1b4cc-cd1c-49c2-80ec-90c9b9591f47)

---

**Update from comments**:

As a workaround, you can try using below:

1. Create a Power Automate flow with trigger "When item is created" for this SharePoint list
2. You can then get the value of ID column from the dynamic content in flow actions
3. Use your logic to concatenate ID with text - save it in a variable or directly do it in update item action
4. Use update item action to update the "second field" in your list with the value calculated in step #3

Comment: Agree with Ganesh Sanap.

Comment: Is there a workaround ? I want to count the IDs of each item submitted and append text to it.

Comment: Check updated answer.